# Proper number format not coming for spanish

Tags: iphone, nsnumberformatter

I am using code below to generate a number for spanish as €1.000.000,00 but I am getting €1,000,000.00. I am using es_ES as locale ID.

```
NSNumberFormatter *frm=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [frm setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"];
    [frm setLocale: locale];
    NSString *symbol = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
    [frm setCurrencySymbol:[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol]];
    NSString *formattedAmt= [frm stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[amount doubleValue]]];
```

Does anyone know why I am not getting proper format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you use `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`?

Comment: I added below, please refer my answer.

Comment: Check my Answer. You have to `setCurrencySymbol` to `@""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` instead of `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` and `CurrencySymbol` to Empty to remove the symbol of **Currency**.

**Working Code :**

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"]];
NSLog(@"Final Value :: %@", [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1000000]]);
```

**Output (As you want without Currency Symbol) :**

> Final Value :: 1.000.000,00